# How to block generic drag&drop handler for images?

Tags: c#, html, blazor

I am learning blazor and I wanted to test moving images programmatically -- I added my handler to mousedown and mousemove and I can see I am moving images. Until the amount of movement triggers generic drag&drop mechanism and my methods are basically blocked.

So I would like to block this generic drag&drop handler and handle moving images on my own. How to do it?

Just for the record, the code:

```
<img src=@tile style="position:fixed; left:@(tileX)px; top:@( tileY)px;  border:none;" 
  @onmousemove="MouseMoved" @onmousedown="MouseDown"/>


@code {
  private string tile = "/images/eye.jpg";
  private int tileX = 0;
  private int tileY = 10;
  private double mouseX = 0;
  private double mouseY = 0;

private void MouseMoved(MouseEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.Buttons==1)
    {
        tileX += (int)Math.Round(args.ScreenX - mouseX);
        tileY += (int)Math.Round(args.ScreenY - mouseY);
        mouseX = args.ScreenX;
        mouseY = args.ScreenY;
    }
}

private void MouseDown(MouseEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.Buttons == 1)
    {
        mouseX = args.ScreenX;
        mouseY = args.ScreenY;
    }
}
```

Comment: What generic d&d handler?

Comment: @Haytam, while you are reading this, there is SO in the left top corner on the page. Start dragging it, you will see a bit shaded copy of the SO image and soon enough you should see black "restricted" icon over it. So this handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/draggable

You can set the img draggable to false

```
<img draggable="false" src=@tile style="position:fixed; left:@(tileX)px; top:@( tileY)px;  border:none;" 
  @onmousemove="MouseMoved" @onmousedown="MouseDown"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to add this in your `img` element in order for it to work:

```
@onmousemove:preventDefault
@onmousedown:preventDefault
```

Here's a working Blazor REPL: https://blazorrepl.com/repl/mYbFaLFB1666hS8h15